# GAE - cron job failing, with no error message in logs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have been trying to run a cron job with GAE (code developed in Python), but when I trigger the job, it fails without any error message -- I can't find anything at all in the logs.

This is happening for a service for which I'm using the flexible environment.

This is the structure of my files:

`my_service.yaml` looks like this:

```
service: my_service
runtime: custom
env: flex

env_variables:
  a:
  b:
```

the `my_service.app` looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import logging

import datetime
import os
import tweepy
from google.cloud import datastore
import time


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/Main')
def hello():
  """A no-op."""
  return 'nothing to see.'

@app.route('/my_service')
def get_service():
    is_cron = request.headers.get('X-Appengine-Cron', False)
    logging.info("is_cron is %s", is_cron)
  # Comment out the following test to allow non cron-initiated requests.
    if not is_cron:
        return 'Blocked.'
    ## data scraping and saving in Datastore

    return 'Done.'

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Then I have a `dispatch.yaml` with this structure:

```
dispatch:

  - url: "*/my_service*"
    service: my_service
```

And a `cron.yaml`:

```
cron:

- description: run my service
  url: /my_service
  schedule: 1 of month 10:00
  target: my_service
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**EDIT**

A bit of context. This is something I'm editing starting from [this repo](https://github.com/amygdala/gae-dataflow/blob/master/sdk_launch/README.md).

The service called `backend` that is defined in there works perfectly (it has also the same schedule in the cron job as `my_service` but when I trigger it in a day different from the one in which it's scheduled, it works just fine). What I did was to create an additional service with its own yaml file, which looks exactly the same as the `beckend.yaml`, its own `my_service.py` and adding it to the `dispacth.yaml`and the `cron.yaml`. In theory this should work, since the structure is exactly the same, but it doesn't.

This service was originally developed in the standard environment and there it was working, the problem originated when I moved it to the flex environment.

**EDIT 2:**

The problem was actually in the Dockerfile, that was calling a service that I was not using.

Comment: Try `- url: "*/my_service/*"`

Comment: @DanCornilescu tried it, but didn't work :/

Comment: anything matching cron requests in the `default` service logs?

Comment: what about if requesting the `/my_service` url manually (curl/browser)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu there are no logs for default service (but it's also because I'm not currently running any). I tried deploying it locally and there is no problem there, so it's just the cron/dispatch file that is not working (I guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

`def get(self):` may have some issues.

First, `get` may be reserved. Second, you aren't able to send `self` to that function.  Change that to:

`def get_service():`

**EDIT2:**

You also need to `import logging` at the top of any page that uses it.  And, you have not imported `Flask` and its components:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template #  etc...
import logging
```

Comment: Removing completely the quotes I get the following error: `(gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/dispatch.yaml]
Unable to assign value '/my_service' to attribute 'url':
invalid url '/my_service'`. I tried re-introducing the quotes, without the wild cards,  and got the same error. Tried with one wild card at the beginning and was able to deploy it but still failing without an error

Comment: Tried this as well, still failing with no message

Comment: I fixed that as well but no change, added a bit more context in the question

Comment: the problem was actually in the dockerfile (so it was not visibile at all from the code I posted). Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your `1 of month 10:00` cron schedule specification can most likely be the culprit: it specifies to run the job at 10:00 **only on the first day** of each month!  From [Defining the cron job schedule](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#defining_the_cron_job_schedule):

> Example: For the `1,2,3 of month 07:00` schedule, the job runs one
>   time at 07:00 on the first three days of each month.

So the last execution happened 3 days ago (if this cron config was deployed at the time) and no other attempt will happen until Nov 1st :)

Change the schedule to something easier to test with, like `every 5 minutes` or `every 1 hours` and revert the change once you're happy it works as expected.

Comment: This shouldn't be the issue since I have other services schedule in the same way and I can manually trigger them. I have tried moving it to `every 5 minutes` but that is not working either.